# Brew error upgrading python

Tags: python, homebrew

I've been having a consistent problem upgrading python3 with homebrew.

When I run "brew upgrade python3", I get

```
==> Upgrading 1 outdated package, with result:
python3 3.6.5
==> Processing python3 formula rename to python
==> Unlinking python3
==> Temporarily unlinking python
Error: Error occurred while migrating.
No such file or directory @ realpath_rec - /usr/local/opt/python
Backing up...
Error: No such file or directory @ realpath_rec - /usr/local/opt/python
==> Upgrading python3 
Error: No such file or directory @ realpath_rec - /usr/local/opt/python
```

Despite failing the upgrade, it has the side-effect of destroying my python3 symlink, so I have to run "brew link python3" afterwards to use it again. This error also screws up brew installs of other packages that depend on python, so it's getting to be pretty bad. Can someone help me fix it?

Edit: I tried "brew uninstall python" and "brew install python" but I get:

```
~$ brew uninstall python
Warning: Use veclibfort instead of deprecated homebrew/science/veclibfort
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.14... (3,614 files, 50.6MB)
Error: No such file or directory @ realpath_rec - /usr/local/opt/python
~$ brew install python
==> Processing python3 formula rename to python
==> Unlinking python3
==> Temporarily unlinking python
Error: Error occurred while migrating.
No such file or directory @ realpath_rec - /usr/local/opt/python
Backing up...
Error: No such file or directory @ realpath_rec - /usr/local/opt/python
Error: python 2.7.14 is already installed
To upgrade to 3.6.5, run `brew upgrade python`
```

Comment: Recently homebrew changed how they package python. Now `brew install python` installs python3.6 as `python3` and `brew install python@2` will install python2.7 as `python`. You shouldn't have any custom symlinks.

Try `brew uninstall python` then `brew install python`.

Comment: Personally, I would suggest using `pyenv` instead of messing with Homebrew Python

Comment: There are some good reasons to use Homebrew Python—e.g., you're using some other Homebrew package that depends on its Python. But if they don't apply, it's usually easier (as of 2018) to use the python.org installer or Anaconda. (Especially now that you can do things like `pip install pyqt5` with python.org Python against Homebrew Qt5, many of which didn't work a couple years ago.)

Comment: I tried "brew uninstall python" then "brew install python". I still get similar errors and it won't update to 3.6.5. I've edited the original post to show the error message. I don't know why /usr/local/opt/python keeps showing up. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: Try `brew uninstall python3` as well?

Comment: Thanks! Yes. It finally worked. I had to uninstall every python installation first.

Comment: Here, "brew uninstall --force --ignore-dependencies python python3 python@2" failed with a complaint about the symlink.  I had to uninstall each version separately, then reinstall:

Comment: Try `brew uninstall --force python` to uninstall all version of python

Comment: Normally, ```brew rm python; rm -rf /usr/local/opt/python; brew prune; brew install python``` should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

I face the issue: `Error: Not a directory @ dir_s_rmdir - /usr/local/Cellar/python3`.

1. try to uninstall python3
   `$ brew uninstall python3`
2. try to install python
   `$ brew install python`
3. try to link the python3

```
$ brew link python@3.8  
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5... 
Error: Could not symlink bin/2to3
Target /usr/local/bin/2to3
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/bin/2to3'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite python@3.8

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run python@3.8
```

4. follow up the tips, remove 2to3
   `$ rm '/usr/local/bin/2to3'`
5. link python@3.8
   `$ brew link --overwrite python@3.8`

fix the error